# Tooltip does not work with Plot and Table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, tooltip

Suppose one has some values and some names:

```
values = {1.5, 2.2, 5.5};
names = {"label1", "label2", "label3"};
```

We now define linear functions using these `values`:

```
f[x_, i_] := values[[i]] * x;
```

Plotting all of these functions with `Table` works as expected:

```
Plot[Table[f[x, i], {i, 1, Length[values]}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

However, adding `Tooltip`s does not work:

```
Plot[Table[Tooltip[f[x, i], names[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[values]}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

The plot graphic is empty. No error message is displayed.

Unrolling the Table manually works as expected:

```
Plot[{
  Tooltip[f[x, 1], names[[1]]], 
  Tooltip[f[x, 2], names[[2]]], 
  Tooltip[f[x, 3], names[[3]]]
}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

How is it possible to plot these functions with `Tooltip`s, without unrolling everything by hand?

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html)

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[
   Tooltip[
    f[x, i]
    , names[[i]]
    ]
   , {i, 1, Length[values]}
   ]
 , {x, 0, 10}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I see why the question may be put on-hold. The relevant documentation on non-standard evaluation can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html).